# PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified

Tags: python, django, docusignapi

I am working on a Django Web App which is used to send documents to users via email and is using Docusign API for that purpose. I am using JWT Grant Authentication and have successfully get the access token which is working fine.

Now, I want to send a document to the user via email for signing purpose. For that, I am using the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from docusign_esign import EnvelopeDefinition, Recipients, Tabs, SignHere, Signer, CarbonCopy, Document, EnvelopesApi, ApiClient
import base64


ACCESS_TOKEN = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'
ACCOUNT_ID = 'MY_ACCOUNT_ID'
BASE_PATH = 'demo.docusign.net/restapi'


def create_document(signer_name, signer_email, cc_name, cc_email):
    return f"""
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
            </head>
            <body style="font-family:sans-serif;margin-left:2em;">
            <h1 style="font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color: darkblue;margin-bottom: 0;">World Wide Corp</h1>
            <h2 style="font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
              margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 3.5em;font-size: 1em;
              color: darkblue;">Order Processing Division</h2>
            <h4>Ordered by {signer_name}</h4>
            <p style="margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em;">Email: {signer_email}</p>
            <p style="margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em;">Copy to: {cc_name}, {cc_email}</p>
            <p style="margin-top:3em;">
                Candy bonbon pastry jujubes lollipop wafer biscuit biscuit. Topping brownie sesame snaps sweet roll pie.
                Croissant danish biscuit soufflé caramels jujubes jelly. Dragée danish caramels lemon drops dragée.
                Gummi bears cupcake biscuit tiramisu sugar plum pastry. Dragée gummies applicake pudding liquorice.
                Donut jujubes oat cake jelly-o.
                Dessert bear claw chocolate cake gummies lollipop sugar plum ice cream gummies cheesecake.
            </p>
            <!-- Note the anchor tag for the signature field is in white. -->
            <h3 style="margin-top:3em;">Agreed: <span style="color:white;">**signature_1**/</span></h3>
            </body>
        </html>
      """


def make_envelope():
    env = EnvelopeDefinition(email_subject='Please sign this document set')
    doc = base64.b64encode(bytes(create_document('user@example.com', 'M Aaqib',
                                                 'user1@example.com', 'Aaqib'), "utf-8")).decode("ascii")
    document = Document(document_base64=doc, name="Order acknowledgement", file_extension="html", document_id="1")
    env.documents = [document]
    signer = Signer(email='user@example.com', name='M Aaqib', recipient_id="1", routing_order="1")
    cc = CarbonCopy(email='user1@example.com', name='Aaqib', recipient_id="2", routing_order="2")
    sign_here = SignHere(anchor_string="**signature_1**", anchor_units="pixels",
                         anchor_y_offset="10", anchor_x_offset="20")
    signer.tabs = Tabs(sign_here_tabs=[sign_here])
    recipients = Recipients(signers=[signer], carbon_copies=[cc])
    env.status = 'sent'
    return env


def worker():
    envelope_definition = make_envelope()
    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.host = BASE_PATH
    api_client.set_default_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}")
    envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
    results = envelopes_api.create_envelope(ACCOUNT_ID, envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
    envelope_id = results.envelope_id
    return {"envelope_id": envelope_id}


def home(request):
    return JsonResponse(worker())
```

But, what I am getting in response is this error:

```
ApiException at /
(401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '153', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '285033cb-cc24-4d43-a6e8-1231a89843c2', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'DA4DFE71', 'Date': 'Sun, 20 Dec 2020 01:13:09 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding'})
HTTP response body: b'{"errorCode":"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."}'
```

I will be extremely thankful if anybody can guide me in this regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically I did a very silly mistake. I was missing `https://` in base path.

It should be: `BASE_PATH = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'`

Instead of: `BASE_PATH = 'demo.docusign.net/restapi'`